# How to get the file path request parameters using get in Spark Java framework?

Tags: java, apache-spark

http://localhost:8000/customer/AppId=API000&FileURL=http://192.0.0.16:8080/test.pdf

I m unable to access AppId and FileURL using the below code.

```
 get("customer/", "application/json", (request, response)->{
   String id = request.queryParams("AppId");
   String path= request.queryParams("FileURL");
   return id+":"+path;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your complete method.

How your code is actually pulling request and response object if this code is written as part of Java class. May Be some annotation is required to be used.

And if this code is written as part of JSP using scriplets then also which JSTL core function are you using, that entire piece should be presented.